# Find contiguous numbers ranges with mysql (25.000+ table rows)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to find contiguous numbers ranges (min, max) from a set of "series" (only numbers).

I have written a SQL using **@row_number** but it works partially. If the row ID (int, primary, auto_increment) is not consecutive, it returns 2 result sets instead of just one.

Check [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32dc8/1) to see how the query works.

So I need to find a way to do this not using @row_number or using it but with a condition to "bind" the 2 results into single one is the series are consecutive (even if the ID is not consecutive).

The correct result should be: (see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32dc8/1))

```
MIN   MAX   PRODUCT_ID
220   230   20
1106  1108  18
1110  1110  18
1112  1120  18
```

Response time is also important.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're after something like this...

```
SELECT a.product_id
     , a.series start
     , MIN(c.series) end 
  FROM card a
  LEFT 
  JOIN card b 
    ON b.product_id = a.product_id
   AND b.series = a.series - 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN card c 
    ON c.product_id = a.product_id
   AND c.series >= a.series
  LEFT 
  JOIN card d 
    ON d.product_id = a.product_id
   AND d.series = c.series + 1
 WHERE b.series IS NULL 
   AND c.series IS NOT NULL
   AND d.series IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.product_id
     , a.series;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32dc8/4

If performance remains an issue, then we can take another look at a solution with @variables

Comment: I've just run your query over my database and it takes forever, in fact I didn't get any results, MySQL Workbench stopped after a while. (table has just 10.000 at the moment and I need to make it work well with 25.000)

Comment: Do you have a composite index on (product_id,series)

Comment: "product_id" is foreign key, "series" has no index

Comment: So, try with a composite index as described.

Comment: A variable solution probably will perform better - but there are others here who are much better than me at those sorts of queries.